# Saving result of 10 fold in different excel files for each fold

Tags: r

I did 10-fold CV. I want to save the result (prediction) of each fold into separate excel file. So far by using this coding write.csv(predictions, 'test1.csv'), it only save the last fold result. How should I do?

```
for(i in 1:10)
{

    testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
    testData <- CAMPUR[testIndexes, ]
    #print(testData)
    #flush.console()

    trainData <- CAMPUR[-testIndexes, ]
    #print(trainData)
    #flush.console()
    model <- NaiveBayes(DIS~., data=trainData, usekernel=TRUE)
    predictions <- predict(model, testData[,1:2])
    write.csv(predictions, 'test1.csv')
    print(predictions)
     flush.console()


    c=confusionMatrix(predictions$class, testData$DIS)
    print(c)
        flush.console()

}
```

Thanks

Comment: instead of `write.csv(predictions, 'test1.csv')`, put `write.csv(predictions, paste0('test',i,'.csv'))`

Comment: user3471465 Please use @CathG 's comment which solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks TimBiegeleisen and CathG . May God Bless you